# Regex that get rid of all the punctuations at the top and the end of a string

Tags: java, regex, string, punctuation

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that gets rid of all the punctuations(if there is one or more) both at the top and the end of a string.
The regex I am using now looks like this:(word is the string I want to convert)

```
    word = word.replaceAll("['?:!.,;]*([a-z]+)['?:!.,;]*", "$1").toLowerCase();
```

However, I still get some weird cases. For example, `'Amen'` goes to `'amen'` and `''tis` goes to `'tis`. Can anyone help me modify it so that `'Amen'` will go to `amen` and `''tis`  to `tis`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following pattern:

```
^\p{P}+|\p{P}+$
```

With an empty string.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vI1zB4/2)

`\p{P}` means *any punctuation character*. The first part of the regex will remove punctuation at the start, and the second will do it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can use:

```
\\p{Punct}
```

to identify a punctuation character.

To remove punctuation character from start or end use this:

```
String word = word.replaceAll("^\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Punct}+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce problem with `''tis` becoming `'tis`, but problem with `'Amen'` is that your regex doesn't accept upper-case characters because `[a-z]` can accept only lower-case characters. You can change it by adding `A-Z` to your character class or by making your regex case insensitive with `(?i)` flag.

So try maybe

```
replaceAll("['?:!.,;]*([a-zA-Z]+)['?:!.,;]*", "$1")
```

or

```
replaceAll("(?i)['?:!.,;]*([a-z]+)['?:!.,;]*", "$1")
```

You can also change your strategy to just removing punctuations at start of the string or at end of the string. In that case you could just use

```
replaceAll("^\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Punct}+$","");
```

where

- `^` represents start of the string
- `$` represents end of the string
- `\\p{Punct}` is character class representing punctuation characters (one of  `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ `` characters) but you can use your own `['?:!.,;]` class if you want